# Problema con una matriz de estados ordenados

Tags: java

tengo un problema, estoy haciendo un programa en java donde se me pide que dado un arreglo de enteros proporcionado por el usuario se me permita ordenarlo con el algoritmo de ordenamiento QuickSort y con el algoritmo Fisher-Yates me lo muestre como queda, y después me muestre una matriz con los estados por los que va pasando esa ordenacion, o sea si lo ordeno con el quicksort que la matriz muestre los estados por los que paso la ordenacion(mi interpretación de lo que pide el profesor es que en la matriz se muestre el proceso de ordenamiento del algoritmo por cada iteración).

Ahora mi problema es el siguiente:
Cuando el programa me devuelve la matriz me la devuelve totalmente con ceros(vale aclarar que estoy recien empezando en este mundo de la programación, o sea, soy estudiante novato).

Ahora esto es lo que tengo hecho:
Una clase para el algoritmo QuickSort
Una clase para el algoritmo Fisher-Yates
Una clase Lista donde declaro mi matriz(adjuntare el codigo)
Una clase EstadoArreglo
Una clase para la interfaz del programa

Este es el codigo de mi clase lista:

```
public class Lista {
    private int[][] matriz;
    private int tamaño;
    
    public Lista() {
        matriz = new int[10][];
        tamaño = 0;
    }
    
    public void agregar(int[] estado) {
        if (tamaño == matriz.length) {
            int[][] nuevaMatriz = new int[2 * matriz.length][];
            System.arraycopy(matriz, 0, nuevaMatriz, 0, tamaño);
            matriz = nuevaMatriz;
        }
        matriz[tamaño] = estado.clone();
        tamaño++;
    }
    
    public int[] obtenerEstado(int indice) {
        if (indice >= 0 && indice < tamaño) {
            return matriz[indice];
        } else {
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("Índice fuera de rango");
        }
    }
    
    public int[] obtenerElemento(int indice) {
        if (indice >= 0 && indice < tamaño) {
            return matriz[indice];
        } else {
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("Índice fuera de rango");
        }
    }
    
    public int obtenerTamaño() {
        return tamaño;
    }
}
```

Este es el de la clase EstadoArreglo:

```
public class EstadoArreglo {
    private int paso;
    private String arreglo;
    
    public EstadoArreglo(int paso, int[] arreglo) {
        this.paso = paso;
        this.arreglo = Arrays.toString(arreglo);
    }
    
    public int getPaso() {
        return paso;
    }
    
    public String getArreglo() {
        return arreglo;
    }
}
```

clase para el algoritmo quicksort

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import ordenador.Ordenador;
/**
 *
 * @author Randy
 */
public class Quicksort implements Ordenador {
    private int[][] matrizEstados;

    @Override
    public void ordenar(int[] arreglo) {
        matrizEstados = new int[arreglo.length][arreglo.length];
        quicksort(arreglo, 0, arreglo.length - 1);
    }

    private void quicksort(int[] arreglo, int inicio, int fin) {
        if (inicio < fin) {
            int indicePivote = particion(arreglo, inicio, fin);
            quicksort(arreglo, inicio, indicePivote - 1);
            quicksort(arreglo, indicePivote + 1, fin);
        }
    }

    private int particion(int[] arreglo, int inicio, int fin) {
        int pivote = arreglo[fin];
        int indiceMenor = inicio - 1;

        for (int i = inicio; i <= fin - 1; i++) {
            if (arreglo[i] <= pivote) {
                indiceMenor++;
                intercambiar(arreglo, indiceMenor, i);
            }
        }

        intercambiar(arreglo, indiceMenor + 1, fin);
        return indiceMenor + 1;
    }

    private void intercambiar(int[] arreglo, int i, int j) {
        int temp = arreglo[i];
        arreglo[i] = arreglo[j];
        arreglo[j] = temp;
    }

    @Override
    public int[][] getMatrizEstados() {
        return matrizEstados;
    }
}
```

clase para el fisher-yates

```
import java.util.Random;
import ordenador.Ordenador;


public class FisherYates implements Ordenador {
    private int[][] matrizEstados;

    @Override
    public void ordenar(int[] arreglo) {
        matrizEstados = new int[arreglo.length][arreglo.length];
        fisherYates(arreglo);
    }

    private void fisherYates(int[] arreglo) {
        Random random = new Random();
        for (int i = arreglo.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
            int j = random.nextInt(i + 1);
            intercambiar(arreglo, i, j);
        }
    }

    private void intercambiar(int[] arreglo, int i, int j) {
        int temp = arreglo[i];
        arreglo[i] = arreglo[j];
        arreglo[j] = temp;
    }

    @Override
    public int[][] getMatrizEstados() {
        return matrizEstados;
    }
}
```

y la case para la interfaz

```
import ordenador.Ordenador;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class InterfazGrafica extends Application {
    private TextArea areaValores;

    private Ordenador ordenador;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        primaryStage.setTitle("Ordenador");

        areaValores = new TextArea();
        areaValores.setPromptText("Ingrese los valores separados por comas");

        Button btnQuicksort = new Button("Quicksort");
        btnQuicksort.setOnAction(e -> ordenarConQuicksort());

        Button btnFisherYates = new Button("Fisher-Yates");
        btnFisherYates.setOnAction(e -> ordenarConFisherYates());

        VBox root = new VBox(10);
        root.setPadding(new Insets(10));
        root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        root.getChildren().addAll(areaValores, btnQuicksort, btnFisherYates);

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 400, 300));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private void ordenarConQuicksort() {
        String valoresTexto = areaValores.getText().trim();
        String[] valores = valoresTexto.split(",");

        int[] arreglo = convertirArreglo(valores);
        if (arreglo == null) {
            mostrarError("Error", "Ingrese valores numéricos separados por comas");
            return;
        }

        ordenador = new Quicksort();
        ordenador.ordenar(arreglo);

        mostrarResultado(arreglo, ordenador.getMatrizEstados());
    }

    private void ordenarConFisherYates() {
        String valoresTexto = areaValores.getText().trim();
        String[] valores = valoresTexto.split(",");

        int[] arreglo = convertirArreglo(valores);
        if (arreglo == null) {
            mostrarError("Error", "Ingrese valores numéricos separados por comas");
            return;
        }

        ordenador = new FisherYates();
        ordenador.ordenar(arreglo);

        mostrarResultado(arreglo, ordenador.getMatrizEstados());
    }

    private int[] convertirArreglo(String[] valores) {
        try {
            int[] arreglo = new int[valores.length];
            for (int i = 0; i < valores.length; i++) {
                arreglo[i] = Integer.parseInt(valores[i].trim());
            }
            return arreglo;
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    private void mostrarResultado(int[] arregloOrdenado, int[][] matrizEstados) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append("Arreglo ordenado: ");
        for (int num : arregloOrdenado) {
            sb.append(num).append(" ");
        }
        sb.append("\n\nMatriz de estados:\n");
        for (int[] fila : matrizEstados) {
            for (int estado : fila) {
                sb.append(estado).append(" ");
            }
            sb.append("\n");
        }
        mostrarMensaje(sb.toString());
    }

    private void mostrarMensaje(String mensaje) {
        Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.INFORMATION);
        alert.setTitle("Resultado");
        alert.setHeaderText(null);
        alert.setContentText(mensaje);
        alert.showAndWait();
    }

    private void mostrarError(String titulo, String mensaje) {
        Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.ERROR);
        alert.setTitle(titulo);
        alert.setHeaderText(null);
        alert.setContentText(mensaje);
        alert.showAndWait();
    }
}
```

Si hace falta algo más por favor haganmelo saber asi como si hay algo mal en el código

Comment: Nos faltaria ver como llenas el array, ya que por lo visto, todo "pareceria" estar bien en lo que mostras...

Comment: gracias por responder, comparto el resto del codigo

Comment: gbianchi, comparti el codigo en la publicacion original, es primera vez que uso stackoverflow, gracias nuevamente

Comment: oik.. es mucho codigo, y dificil de seguir.. ataca tus problemas de a 1... yo en todo tu codigo, no veo donde realmente estas ordenando algo que no sea lo que pasaste, y que para colmo se pierde porque esta todo en variables locales... segui tu codigo, hace debug linea por linea.. nunca estas ordenando lo que pasas.. ordenas una copia, que para colmo se pierde....

Comment: emepeza simplificando QS.. muchas clases para un novato te van a confundir y marear...

Comment: gracias nuevamente, voy a hacer lo que me sugieres, tratare de simplificar mucho mas el codigo porque es lo que dices hasta yo mismo estoy confundido jaja, luego compartire mis avances

Answer (score 0):

Más allá de los posibles errores de tu código (no lo he analizado), te muestro uno de los tantos caminos que se pueden tomar...

La clase **Quicksort**:
agregamos un atributo

```
String data = "";
```

agregamos unas lineas en el método **quicksort**.

```
private void quicksort( int[] arreglo, int inicio, int fin ) {

      // agregamos a "data" el primer número del array (convertido a cadena)
   data += arreglo[ 0 ];

      // iteramos sobre el resto de números agregándolos después de un espacio
   for( int i = 1; i < arreglo.length; i++ ) {
      data += " " + arreglo[ i ];
   }

      // agregamos un salto de linea
   data += "\n";
   if( inicio < fin ) {
      int indicePivote = partition( arreglo, inicio, fin );
      quicksort( arreglo, inicio, indicePivote - 1 );
      quicksort( arreglo, indicePivote + 1, fin );
   }
   mostrar();
}
```

creamos el método mostrar.

```
void mostrar() {

         // creamos un array separando a "data" por lineas
      String aux[] = data.split( "\n" );

         // creamos la matriz de salida
      int matriz[][] = new int[ aux.length ][ 10 ];

         // iteramos sobre las filas de la matriz
      for( int i = 0; i < matriz.length; i++ ) {

            // creamos un array de las fila recorrida
         String aux2[] = aux[ i ].split( " " );

            // iteramos sobre las columnas de la matriz
         for( int j = 0; j < matriz[ 0 ].length; j++ ) {

               // instanciamos la matriz con el valor de "aux2" parseado
            matriz[ i ][ j ] = Integer.parseInt( aux2[ j ] );            
         }         
      }
      h.v( matriz );
}
```

Puedes aplicar el mismo criterio para el otro algoritmo.